# Is localstorage the right choice for this webapp?

Tags: html, local-storage, offlineapps

I'm interested in building a small offline webapp and I'm looking for some advice. Here's the basics of what I want it to do

- Create reports that, initially, will just have a name and text field
- List, edit, and delete these notes
- Ideally I'd like to add more fields to the reports later

Is localstorage a good option for storing this type of data locally? If so, can anybody direct me to a complete list of the commands for interacting with it in javascript? e.g. setItem, getItem, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localstorage will work just fine for this, but don't think of it as a robust solution.. It's just a basic key/value store and won't be very performant with thousands of complex things going on.

Check out the excellent Dive into HTML5 guide on localstorage: 
http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 0):

[Link to the localstorage apis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage)

Yes localstorage would be perfect for you application. It would allow your application to have no need to connect to a server at all. Keep in mind that local storage does have maximums on the amount of data that can be stored.

EDIT:
Using `JSON.stringify()` on can convert complex javascript objects to json which can be storage and retrieved with ease inside of local storage.