# PHP Web app is going to take up lots of memory. How can I set a limit or store that memory?

Tags: php, memory

A PHP web app that I am going to initiate soon is going to take up lots of memory.

How can I set a limit to tell it to stop when it reaches a certain point? What is a good limit?

It takes up lots of memory because it is recursive, but I have a limit of how many recursive calls it can make from one of the initial calls.

But, I still want to have a memory cap. How can I do this?

Can I use any type of local storage not on the server, but on the user's machine? Or is it inappropriate to do that?

**Update: Most of my questions were answered in the first answer, but I am still wondering how to set a memory limit in PHP.**

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Comment: What do you mean by "lots of memory"? Kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes, etc.? "lots" does not mean anything unless we know a lot more about the scale of the project, the architecture, and exactly what you are planning to do.

Comment: @Dagon Thank you, how do use it thought. Do you have an example or sample code?

Comment: the page linked to has several example

Comment: @Dagon I don't see example code anywhere. Just explanations.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Try to improve your question to get more constructive answers.

Answer (score 2):

The right answer to this question would depend on a description of your needs. To say your app is recursive is pretty generic and doesn't tell us a whole lot about what you are trying to achieve.

Personally, I would receive user input and if I knew the response to the user was going to be a lot of data, I would make sure my server does all the heavy lifting in a processing queue independent of the API request. The user should not have to wait long periods for response. So you have your back end processing this recursive method and store the results into a cache file, or cache blocks and serve them back to the user in chunks.

This is very generic, but since we don't really know what your actual goal is, it's kind of all I can say about it.

Feel free to update your question with specifics and maybe I will update my answer to better fit your needs.

And yes, you can store on the local for the user. Look into html5 localstorage. See this answer: [Is localstorage the right choice for this webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217313/is-localstorage-the-right-choice-for-this-webapp)
It is common to make web apps store locally so the app can function offline or in areas of poor service. Think convention centers or large structures where service is typically poor or unavailable. Inappropriate only applies if you foolishly attempt to store private data in a way that is easily accessible. Otherwise, it is just what comes with the use of your app.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I don't think that local storage is the right choice for this, but I now know more about it. Thank you.
However, what I am making is a web crawler that crawls part of the web. It is a crawl() function that recursively calls other pages the initial page links to. Then I sort through the content and store what I need. What should I do with this. I think it would be bad to store it in the memory. I am planning on echo-ing it. How can I store it on the server? Or should I use local storage for this?

Comment: Is there a limit to local storage? I think using modernizr to detect for local storage and use local storage when necessary is a good idea, but server storage when not supported. But how can I put the php inside the js?

Comment: typically that data would be stored in a db

Comment: You could store references to your server instead of whole data sets on the user's device. So each app generates a unique ID if one is not set, then you store that ID on the local storage and use it to call your service and return the processed data to the user. Minimize the amount of data the user has to keep themselves. Offline, this could be a challenge if the user has to keep access to all data fetched, but this naturally depends on what you promise to make available.

Comment: There wouldn't be a need for PHP inside js - however one wants to translate that. You can store anything PHP served back in any number of ways.

Comment: @KaiQing Okay, you talked me out of using local storage. I;m only going to use server-side storage from now on.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, PHP executes *only* on the server. So your last paragraph about "on the user's machine" is completely irrelevant to the PHP memory issue.

Secondly, you should know the limits of your recursive algorithm! It should stop, when it is *supposed* to stop - aka. when it reaches the [**base case**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Recursive_functions_and_algorithms) of the recursive algorithm.  You aren't actually asking about setting PHP's memory limit to control how your program runs, are you? Just because you're calling a recursive function doesn't mean that your application is guaranteed to use a lot of memory.

Finally, if you are convinced that your PHP script is behaving the way you intend it to, but it simply requires more memory than it is allowed, you can increase the limit. There have been many, [many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20memory%20limit) asked about how to do this.