# How do I save client side data from a vue single page app to something like a excel or pdf file so the user can download it on a button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a small product configurator written as a frontend only vue app. the function is similar to for example those configurators on Car manufacturer websites where you can change the color, wheels and so on, see your choices visually and get a list of chosen "extras" at the end of the process...

Likewise in my app the customer will get visual feedback and also the data (length, height, type,... ) according to his chosen config will be handed over to the last page of the process where a table of contents for his configuration will be displayed. And the data should be attached to a file which the user can then download.

As I'm relatively new to web-programming and also vue, I'm having a hard time on the best approach for a frontend only, at best vue/js only solution so I can pull that data and show it in the table and safe it to the file,

Also whether it's better to do both things independent or maybe easier to pull the data into the table where it is shown in a structured way and from there push it onto the file?

Data is handed over as numbers and strings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is localstorage the right choice for this webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217313/is-localstorage-the-right-choice-for-this-webapp) - Perhaps you just didn't know to ask about the `localStorage` API.

Comment: Convert json to CSV https://medium.com/@danny.pule/export-json-to-csv-file-using-javascript-a0b7bc5b00d2

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate per se even though I did not know about the localStorage API but i will try it out and come back if it won't work. Thx so far